# C# Unity Engine destroy() subclass

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

Hello i have this code:

```
public abstract class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void OnStart();
    public abstract void OnUpdate();

    private void Start()
    {
        OnStart();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
        OnUpdate()
    }
}
```

then I have the this:

```
public class SecondTest : Test
{
    public override void OnStart()
    {

    }

    public override void OnUpdate()
    {
        Writter.Log("Running");
    }
}
```

However whenever I press X, my writter keeps logging, it seems like the instance of "Test" gets destroyed but not my "SecondTest" is there any way to solve this? thank you!

Comment: Do you have code you can show us that actually compiles?

Comment: @RobertHarve the code is actually pretty big but this is the only part i'm running at the moment, I've added prints in after the Input.GetKeydown and the destroy is getting called properly but its not destroying the subclass. I'm trying to figure out if i've made a mistake somehow but the code is really simple

Comment: Well, at a minimum, I think we'd need to see the code for `Destroy()`.  Does `Writter` even exist? (You've misspelled it)  Does it matter that you're calling Destroy in the first class, but not the second?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Destroy() is inherited from MonoBehaviour in unity engine, and Writter does exist it just writes text to a txt file for debugging (it works fine as well) and yes basically the only reason i'm making the first class is because there will be a lot of 2nd classes made, and they all need to be destroyed by the same key didn't want to have to add Destroy to all of them as i thought this should work

Comment: @RobertHarvey it seems like you put my question on hold but don't really know about the MonoBehaviours from unity which are tagged on the post, I'm new in this site so i don't know if this matters much.

Comment: I'll reopen your post, but I don't think you're going to get an answer unless you can be a little clearer about what you want.

Comment: Is Update actually called in the base class? Breakpoint reached when placed on Destory(this);

Comment: @RLS , yes update is called in the base class and same for OnUpdate() on the second class, Destroy is also called on the base class but it seems like it destroys the base class and not the secondary one

Comment: I'm not familiar with unity/mono but does destroy occur immediately or would you need to return right after destroy so it doesn't execute onupdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OP explained the intention is to cause Children to be destroyed when Parent is.

1. The solution would probably be better handled at a '(Test)Manager' or 'LevelManager'.
2. You could assign your Children or prefabs to your (Test)Manager manually, or get (Test)Manager to instantiate the child prefab.

   ```
   GameObject child = Instantiate(prefab); 
   child.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform); //set the child's parent to the Manager
   ```
3. Then in your (Test)Manager

   ```
   private void Update()
   {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
       {
           for(int i=0;i<gameObject.transform.childCount;i++)
              Destroy(gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
       }
   }
   ```

This is just a crude suggestion, there are probably better ways to do this such as holding some references to the children in the manager versus parenting.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, the only reason why i'm doing this is because I will be having a lot of "SecondTest" classes and I wanted all of them to be destroyed on keypress X, I was trying to avoid having to add a check into each class "if the key is press then destroy()" so I was wondering if it was possible to destroy set a destroy key for all of them in the parent class, hopefully I explained myself well enough, thanks again for the help!

Comment: ah okay... so you want the Parent to destroy the Children, kk. That explains why you are in this predicament. However, the solution to this won't be with the child. Let me change my answer